# ＲでVARモデルを使おうとするとエラーがでます。

Tags: r

Ｒの`vars`パッケージの`VARselect`関数を使うと以下のエラーがでます。

> Error in `lm.fit(x = ys.lagged, y = yendog)` : `x` の中に `NA`/`NaN`/`Inf` があります
>
> In addition: Warning messages: 1: In `lm.fit(x = ys.lagged, y = yendog)` : `NA`s introduced by coercion
>
> 2: In `lm.fit(x = ys.lagged, y = yendog)` : `NA`s introduced by coercion

データには欠損値はありません。なぜエラーが出るのでしょうか？
当方プログラミング初心者のため、基本的なエラーかもしれませんがご教示いただけますと幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

[良いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)を参考にするともっと良い解答が得られると思います。

```
library(vars)

VARselect(Canada)  # エラーが出ない
VARselect(iris)    # エラーが出る (数値以外の情報が含まれているため)

is.numeric(Canada)  # [1] TRUE
is.numeric(iris)    # [1] FALSE

# 以下の3つあたりを実行すれば原因が解るかもしれません
is.numeric(xxx)                  # 全て数値のデータか否か (FALSEだとまずい)
any(is.na(xxx))                  # NAを含むか否か (TRUEだとまずい)
any(is.infinite(as.matrix(xxx))) # Infを含むか否か (TRUEだとまずい)
```

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます。